# The current identity (NT Authority/Network Service) does not have write access to

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I developed a simple web application. A label and a button. On click of Button, the label will display Hello World.

When I deploy this web application on my web server and access the URL, I get this error message.

> The current identity (NT
>   Authority/Network Service) does not
>   have write access to
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\

I have tried the following -

Navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 and typed the following command -

```
aspnet_regiis -ga "NT Authority\Network Service"
```

After that also, it did not work.

We checked the permissions of the folder Temporary ASP.NET Files and for the Network Service user, we checked the Security Permissions and it has all the permissions as required.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me, didn't try the -ga:

Navigate to

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

and type the following command

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

Comment: +1 This solution fixed my problem which was caused by demoting a domain controller (cdonner's answer).

Comment: Even i was facing the same problem, this worked for me. thank you @Adam

Comment: Also worked for me. I had a server with SQL RS installed, and then promoted it to a DC.

Comment: I needed to do this for both Framework\v4.0.30319.0 and Framework64\v4.0.30319.0.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error while replacing my domain server at home that hosts a bunch of websites, mostly data collection services for temperature etc. It also runs SSRS that I use to produce charts.
I built new hardware and demoted the old box. It is no longer a DC, but a regular member of the domain. When I moved a website to the new server and tried to hit it, I got this error.

Running aspnet_regiis did not change anything. Now it turns out that the site calls the Reporting Services web service that still pointed to the old server, and that the error message is actually coming from the demoted former domain controller. I had to run aspnet_regiis -i on the old server!

Takeaways:

1. Demoting a PDC can cause the permissions to get messed up,
   resulting in this error
2. The error may not come from your local
   machine - look beyond the obvious!

Comment: +1 Thanks.  Demoting a DC caused this error but Adam's solution fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Eugene, You can get it working with high enough privilege like LocalSystem, but keep in mind that LocalSystem has administrator privileges on the local server and can also access network resources under the computer account, so if you application gets exploited, the attacker can get access to a lot of resources. Network Service on the other hand is just a user account on the local server and is also accessing network resources in the computer account context.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would check when you are give permission to the Temporary ASP.NET folder using Folder Properties->Security option is if your are giving setting permission for right Network Service account. This can happen if the Network Service user the dialog is finding is for different location and not the local instance.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Identity of the application pools to use LocalSystem account as opposed to Network Service. Recycled the Application pools and everything was ok. This resolved it for me. I think there is an underlying issue with the "Network Service" on my server as I had problems with SQL using this account. Again just used LocalSystem during the install to get passed that also.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the Application Pool identity to NETWORKSERVICE
And then add the user connecting to my website (the user you 'connect as' in IIS settings under `Basic Settings` for your website) to the IIS_IUSRS group

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a case where the 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files' directory was missing (as well as the Framework64 version: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files). I created the missing "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory in each parent directory and the web app started working. So if you every delete the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory itself, recreate it so you do not run into this issue.