# ASP.NET -The current identity (Machine\ASPNET) does not have write access to 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'

Tags: iis-5

I am having this issue on my Win XP Professional Development Machine. My application is on Virtual Directory.

The current identity (MachineName\ASPNET) does not have write access to 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.

I have done following so far.

```
    1. Must Not Use Simple File Sharing. After Changing Settings, Pls Reboot.

               Open your My Computer, the on menu, select Tool >> Folder Option the Select View Tab,

               Uncheck Use Simple File Sharing

  2  Adding User Permission

             When you create virtual directory on IIS, the actual folder you used with it must have access permission

             To do this, follow:

            select the properties of your actual folder, then select Sharing Tab
            select option Share This Folder
            specify the ShareName (commonly folder name itself)
            then select Security tab, you will see the Group and Username listed there.
            to add ASPNET just click ADD
            pop up window will appear "Select User or Group"
            Click Advance  and Click Find Now
            All Users and Group will be listed there, try to find ASPNET and select OK
            you will going to back on Security tab and select something like "RAD/ASPNET", under that you will see "Permission for ASP.NET"
            for the last step, check Full Control under Allow Column, then OK



3 I Have tried, the aspnet_regiis exe in the framework folder!
```

Still does not work, Any other options or suggestions please..

**Update:
My Hard disk is completely encrypted. Does it have any impact?**

Comment: I was facing the same problem ,visit this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9187636/1054978 it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypted shouldn't affect.

Try going to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files in a file windows explorer and give all access to your ASPNET and Network accounts.

Comment: I have done that. But I think the Access Policy on the Laptop are changing every two minutes as the laptop is controlled by Network Guys.. Anyways Thanks. I have sorted that issue